# How do I reset default .bashrc (debian wheezy)?

Tags: debian, bashrc

I messed up my .bashrc file. How do I get to the default one that was initially created with my home directory?

Comment: Whoops. Shoulda done some more research. Here is the answer for posterity: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/deleted-my-bashrc-file-accidently-i-am-a-debian-user-what-should-i-do-801315/

it's in /etc/skel/.bashrc in my particular case

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.messed
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score -2):

I do not remember the exact commands, but there is a way to see which files do belong to a package, like bash....

Look for bashrc.sample or bashrc.example or bashrc.default and just copy it to your home directory..